# Étalé space for sheaf of sections of a fiber bundle

Tags: algebraic-topology, sheaf-theory, fiber-bundles

Let $X$ be a topological space, $\pi:E\to X$ a fiber bundle over $X$ with fiber $F$ and structure group $G$. Let $\mathcal{F}$ denote the sheaf of continuous sections of the bundle. I probably want to assume $X$ has some reasonable topological properties.

Is there any nice description for the [étalé space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sheaf_(mathematics)#The_.C3.A9tal.C3.A9_space_of_a_sheaf) of $\mathcal{F}$? When $F$ is discrete, i.e. $E$ is a covering space, I would say E itself can be chosen as étalé space. But how about "bigger" F?

Comment: There is no nice description, because the espace étalé itself is not nice. For instance, the one corresponding to the sheaf of smooth functions on a smooth manifold is not even Hausdorff.

Answer (score 5):

The étalé space is an object $\pi:E\to X$ of the slice category $\mathrm{Top}_{/X}$, where $X$ is an object of $\mathrm{Top}$, such that $\pi$ is a local homeomorphism. See that [there is an equivalence of categories between $\mathrm{Etale}_{/X}$ of étalé spaces over $X$ and the category $\mathrm{Shv}_{X}$ of sheaves on $X$](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/etale+space#relation_to_sheaves). A nice way of seeing this is by noting that there is an isomorphism between the sheaf of sections of $\mathrm{Etale}(\mathscr{F})$ and $\mathscr{F}$ itself, and is a form of sheafification. See page $50$ of [these notes](http://people.math.umass.edu/~mirkovic/A.COURSE.notes/1.AlgebraicGeometry/B.Chapters/89.pdf) and [Planetmath](http://planetmath.org/etalespace).

Comment: Thanks for the nice references. I'm interested in the case $F$ is discrete. It looks like the equivalence of categories you talk about restricts to a correspondence between locally constant sheaves and fiber bundles with discrete fibers. I mean that the étalé space of a locally constant sheaf with stalks $A$ really looks like a fiber bundle with fiber $A$, if we put on $A$ the discrete topology. Does this work?

Comment: @Lor: None of the attached links seems work. Do you know where I can find the first notes?

Comment: @Bumblebee unfortunately that link seems broken. Have a look at this one https://people.math.umass.edu/~mirkovic/A.Notes/1.AlgebraicGeometry/0.2004/B.Chapters/89.pdf